# B2 visa - traveling every year for 6 months and then traveling to UK?

Tags: b1-b2-visas

Hi my parents have B2 visa which is valid for 10 years and they also have tourist visa to UK where my brother resides. Can they travel every year to the US and stay for 6 months and then go to UK and stay there for 6 months? Effectively not staying in India at all? Will this cause problems if this is done every year? They are around 65 years.

Thank you for the responses. Their funding for their stay is done by me and my brother. Haven't really thought of the health issues currently. I am just not sure if its legally ok to continuously do this for the coming years.

Comment: How are they funding this travel without work visas? That question is going to be front and foremost in the minds of both US and UK immigration authorities.

Comment: @Moo presumably with retirement savings and possibly contributions from their children.  It seems almost feasible, though I note that one oft overlooked and little enforced requirement for US B visas (among other categories) is to have a residence in a foreign country with no intention of abandoning it.

Comment: @phoog it’s feasible, if the issue of overcoming proof of funding is solved - however, they will have to be tax resident in one or the other of those two countries if they are not intending to spend a significant time in India.  You don’t have to have residency or leave to remain in order to be deemed tax resident in most countries, so that’s something to consider.  Another thing as elderly people is the issue of health cover - they wouldn’t be eligible for non-emergency NHS care, which means expensive private health plans (you can’t pay the Immigrant Health Surcharge on a visitor visa).

Comment: According to [UK Standard Visitor visa Eligibility](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/eligibility), "Your visa may be cancelled and you may get a long-term ban on visiting if your travel history shows you’re repeatedly living in the UK for extended periods.".

Comment: @phoog of course there is the other issue that they are effectively trying to live in the UK for extended periods of time on a visitor visa, something expressly forbidden. We often see it here linked to repeated visits in a short time period, but this would almost certainly count.

Comment: @moo Didn't know about tax resident part. They are not currently tax resident in either USA or UK. They only pay tax in India. It appears that UK tourist visa are slightly more restricted than in USA?

Comment: They will be stopped at some point and their visas revoked. That’s a virtual guarantee.

Comment: @Moo the US will eventually consider them tax residents under the substantial presence test unless they have a "closer connection" to another country, which I doubt they'd be able to show in this scenario.  But otherwise, they would be fine.  Because of Florida and Hawaii, the US is well accustomed to retirees spending six months in the country every year in B-2 status.  Those people usually pass the closer connection test and avoid tax residence as a consequence.  It's possible that the UK would also consider them tax residents; I don't know those rules.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan someone who spends half the year in the UK is butting up against the edge of what's accepted, but in theory it should be fine.

Comment: @phoog it’s not that simple - I know, I’ve been through it myself.  The UK goes through quite a complicated “statutory residence test” series of scenarios, it’s not just a case of “been in the country for more than half the year” (but if you did, then that’s an automatic “yes”).  In this case, it’s probable that they would be found to be UK tax resident under the sufficient ties test or the homes test if they kept this up for 3 years.

Comment: @phoog unless you were referring to the US situation in your last comment, in which case ignore the above (but I will leave it so people can understand the complexity of the situation)

Comment: @ Moo no, my last comment was a bit unfocused.  Most of it is about the US, but the last sentence is about the UK.  It was intended to raise the possibility that both countries would consider them tax residents.  The US test is also more complicated than that, but the effect of the test on someone who spends half of each year in the country is fairly simple to determine: they become a tax resident as of the second year unless they also pass the closer connection test.

Comment: @fictionreader How long are their UK visitor visas valid for?